# How to effectively remove updated HashSet items

Tags: java, hashset

Given the following snippet, how do we effectively remove elements on which have been previously updated/changed?

```
public static class Foo {
    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return new Random().nextInt();
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Set<Foo> set = new HashSet<>();

    set.add(new Foo());
    set.removeIf(f -> true); // Returns true, but no deletion occurs

    assert set.size() == 0; // Fails as set still contains it's single item
}
```

Note: The above snippet is intended to simulate a different `Foo` upon next call to `Object::hashCode` (on Set::remove and Set::removeIf).

**EDIT:**

For those who did not understand the "random hash" part, here is a different view of the problem stated above:

```
public static class Bar {

    public String firstName;
    public String lastName;

    public Bar() {
        this(null, null);
    }

    public Bar(String firstName, String lastName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int result = 1;

        result *= 59 + (firstName == null ? 43 : firstName.hashCode());
        result *= 59 + (lastName == null ? 43 : lastName.hashCode());

        return result;
    }

}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Set<Bar> set = new HashSet<>();

    String originalFirstName = "FOO";
    String updatedFirstName = "FOO_CHANGED";

    // Create bar
    Bar bar = new Bar();
    bar.firstName = originalFirstName;
    bar.lastName = "BAR";

    // Add bar
    set.add(bar);

    // Change bar
    System.out.println("Bar hash (now): " + bar.hashCode());
    bar.firstName = updatedFirstName;
    System.out.println("Bar hash (new): " + bar.hashCode());

    Bar oldBar = new Bar(originalFirstName, bar.lastName);
    Bar changedBar = new Bar(bar.firstName, bar.lastName);

    System.out.println("Old bar hash:     " + oldBar.hashCode()); // Hash matches old value
    System.out.println("Changed bar hash: " + changedBar.hashCode()); // Hash matches new value

    set.remove(oldBar); // Removes no elements (returns false)
    set.remove(changedBar); // Removes no elements (returns false)
    set.removeIf(f -> true); // Removes no elements (returns true)

    Iterator<Bar> iterator = set.iterator();

    while (iterator.hasNext()) {
        iterator.next();
        iterator.remove(); // Fails silently
    }

    assert set.size() == 0;
}
```

There's no random hash at all.

There are different hashes indeed, but apparently the elements can never be removed if they have ever been changed (therefore, their hash), regardless what. We can confirm that on both `Set::remove` calls, where `set.remove(oldBar)` should have removed the element as `oldBar` hash equals to the hash when `bar` was added.

Comment: The contract behind `hashCode()` says that the value must return the same value when called multiple times, so having a random value is not a good choice.

Comment: @MAnouti as stated on the post, multiple calls to `Object::hashCode` results in different values whether the object properties have changed or not. Consider an object with two string properties, a null one and another with any non-null value. Assign a new non-null value to the previously null property and that would result in different hash values.

Comment: @Henri As [commented by M Anouti](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65834166/how-to-effectively-remove-updated-hashset-items#comment116399709_65834166), that is exactly the behavior that disqualifies an object from being put in a `HashSet`.

Comment: @BasilBourque what's your point, though? If an element is added to a set and is changed later on, are you saying that it will last there forever? That element apparently can never be removed even if using the same hash value when it was added. I added a different example on my post.

Comment: @Henri Have you really not read the Javadoc nor the quotes from that documentation posted here? The doc clearly states that you cannot be changing the hash code by which the object is stored in a `HashSet`. Wishful thinking on your part does not change that. Perhaps you want a collection that observes its contained objects for changes to its hash code value. `HashSet` is *not* such a collection. To make a change to an object that will alter its hash code value, first remove it from the set, make your mutation on the object, and resubmit the object to the set.

Answer (score 4):

*As all other answers and comments, firstly, I should say that `hashCode` should remain consistent: it supposed remain the same when an element is stored in a hash based collection.*

---

Amusingly, the code snippet **in OpenJDK 11 will return `0`** when the set's `size` is queried, but on OpenJDK 8 it will remain 1.

This happened due to changes in the standard library (see [JDK-8170733](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8170733)):

- The `removeIf` in `HashMap#keySet` (`HashSet` uses a `HashMap` underneath) is not overridden, so it relies on `Iterator#remove`.
- Implementation of the latter method has been changed to avoid recomputing the `hashCode` inside the `HashMap.HashIterator::remove` method.
- So the `removeIf` will successfully remove elements
- See [this](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/commit/36779a0df3e2c7942dda40d502d8bd3848e1364e) commit:

  ```java
  -            K key = p.key;
  -            removeNode(hash(key), key, null, false, false);
  +            removeNode(p.hash, p.key, null, false, false);
  ```

---

Once again: **do not rely rely on this implementation detail**

Comment: woaa just pasted the same thing. Was curious about that also

Answer (score 3):

The problem here is that if you modify the object in such a way that the hashcode is different then it is no longer structurally the same object. Another way to say this, `original.equals(modified)` is `false` (or at least should be due to the contracts of `equals()` and `hashCode()`. One solution is to modify `hashCode()` to calculate based on some invariant. In other words, the returned hashcode is only based on the identifying data in a `Foo` object that will never change no matter what. For example, this could be an `id`, such as for an object that maps to an underlying database table.

Alternatively, you could find a different data structure that matches your use case better. For example an `ArrayList` might be more appropriate since you can remove items at a given index regardles of the state of that object.

Comment: Sets must be used. Also, I've updated the post to explain the "random hash" part.

Answer (score 1):

Not consistent hashCode is wrong.

However I could not understand how it should affect you in your case as you invoke removeIf which iterates all elements of the set.

So I tried it using JAVA 11 and it worked. Set was emptied and size returned was 0 as expected. I am curious of what configurations you use.

```
   public static void main(String[] args){

        Set<Foo> s = new HashSet<>();
        s.add(new Foo("user1", 3));
        s.add(new Foo("user2", 5));

        s.forEach( e -> System.out.println(e));

        s.removeIf(f-> true);

        s.forEach( e ->System.out.println(e));

        System.out.println(s.size());

    }
```

[image]

Comment: Apparently this is an algorithm issue as stated by Denis, which have been solved onwards Java 11. Saldy I'm using Java 8 (and can't update).